# create a REST connection string parameter

Tags: sql, rest, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS project and i want to connect to a rest service that the user will give me.
I want to deploy this SSIS project and have a project parameter that will include this parameter string. is this possible?
i am doing this with my SQL databases connections.

Answer (score 0):

from what i manged to find out there is no option to put a parameter with the connection string. there is an option to have an input of your WSDL/IP and parse the SSIS XML to change the old value to the new one.